# In a moderated regression does the strength of the moderation effect depend on the strength of the relationship between X and Y?

Tags: regression, interaction

In a moderated regression predicting Y, is there a relationship between the strength of the moderation effect for the interaction term X*Z and the strength of the relationship between X and Y?